# Entity Framework 7 one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating an application in ASP.NET 5 and EF 7 with code first. I created my classes and `DbContext` to create database and tables when the application is first time executed.

So here is my concept. I have total of 3 tables (`Status`, `PackageVersion`, and `DeploymentLog`).

`PackageVersion` and `DeploymentLog` have a foreign key `StatusId`. So `Status` table can have multiple `DeploymentLogs` and `PackageVersions`.

When I run the application in Visual Studio, I get an exception.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_DeploymentLog_Status_StatusId' on table 'DeploymentLog' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

However, when I comment out `[Required]` from both `PackageVersion` and `DeploymentLog` classes and add question mark like this `int?` in both classes `public int? StatusId { get; set; }` to make it optional; database and tables get generated without any issues.

Here is my code:

`packageversion` code:

```
public class PackageVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string PackageName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

`DeploymentLog` code:

```
public class DeploymentLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PackageVersionId { get; set; }
    public PackageVersion PackageVersion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

`Status` code:

```
public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` code:

```
public class AutomationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public AutomationDBContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PackageVersion> PackageVersions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeploymentLog> DeploymentLogs { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried adding `protected override onModelCreating` in DBContext class, but I still run in to same issue. Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<DeploymentLog>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Status)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Status>(s => s.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PackageVersion>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Status)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Status>(s => s.Id);
}
```

Comment: sorry about that. Just updated my post and added `status` class.

Answer (score 2):

All I had to do in order to make the migration work in EF7 was to remove `StatusId` properties and make the navigation properties `virtual`. Following is what my `DbContext` looks like:

```
public class PackageVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string PackageName { get; set; }        
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}

public class DeploymentLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual PackageVersion PackageVersion { get; set; }        
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PackageVersion> PackageVersions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeploymentLog> DeploymentLogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

This produces as expected ERD:

[image]

Comment: @Ibrahim, thank you for your response. However, `.HasRequired` and `WillCascadeOnDelete` are no longer available in `EF7`. :(

Comment: My bad. I was working with EF 6. I will see if I can do the same in EF7.

Comment: @Ray I have edited my answer after trying your models on ASP.NET 5 app with EF 7.

Comment: thank you. That would definitely fix the problem. However, another problem I will run into is that I will not able use the Model to post or put data because `statusId`  property no longer exist in Model class. I guess I have to create viewModel with `statusId` property in it. You think thats wise to do?

Comment: @Ray Yes that's exactly what we do. You don't want to use your entity models for you action model binding. View models are your best bet to take whatever user data and then map it to your entity models.

Comment: I think in my domain model, I still have to use `statusId` property, otherwise viewModel that is bind to domain model will not able to find `statusId` property if I only use `statusid` property in viewModel.

Comment: @Ray When you get `StatusId` from your ViewModel, you will be using EF to query and get the `Status` entity corresponding to the id and then attach that object to your `PackageVersion` or `DeploymentLog`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling cascading delete with Fluent API (not possible with data annotations):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PackageVersion>()
        .HasOne(s => s.Status)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Status>(s => s.Id)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

and should add "virtual" on

```
public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
```

check this out
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620

Comment: `WillCascadeOnDelete` is not available in `EF7` :( maybe I need to open a bug issue in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

DeploymentLog have two reference to Status, one directly and another indirectly throughout PackageVersion. For me this is code smell. 

You can keep out of troubles by not sharing Status table for them. As your model is right now, I probably will use enum, as a single string attribute does not have that much weight to model an object. As an alternative will be to use Status as a lookup table.